# Numpy, masking and sklearn clustering

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I am having an issue with modifying 3D to 2D in order to supply it to Bandwidth function for mean shift calculation.  Originally I query the DB for the data in 1D array of values and set of IDś that belong to these values - this will help me later to identify the sources. Prior to calculation I add one more dimension to ensure calculation will go right and all of these results are being kept in 3D array. Now I need to supply 2D containing a value and a zero to the calculating function, but I am having trouble constructing 2D compressed (without thrid value describing ID) array for that. Does anyone know how to do it using numpy and not having a completely separate list containing ID's?

Source array:

```
[(2.819999933242798, 0.0, 16383) 
 (3.75, 0.0, 16384) 
 (3.75, 0.0, 16385)]
```

Array after it has been masked:

```
[(2.819999933242798, 0.0, --) 
 (3.75, 0.0, --) 
 (3.75, 0.0, --)]
```

Array as it needs to be:

```
[(2.819999933242798, 0.0) 
 (3.75, 0.0) 
 (3.75, 0.0)]
```

Cheers

Comment: It looks like you have a list of tuples, not a numpy array.  If you do have a numpy array of that format, it seems like you just want to get rid of the last column, which you could do with `arr[:,:-1]`.

Answer (score 1):

You could first convert to a numpy array:

```
h=[(2.819999933242798, 0.0, 16383), (3.75, 0.0, 16384) , (3.75, 0.0, 16385)]
a=np.array(h)
```

and then get the columns you want:

```
a[:,0:2]
```

gives:

```
array([[ 2.81999993,  0.        ],
       [ 3.75      ,  0.        ],
       [ 3.75      ,  0.        ]])
```

Or `a[:,:-1]` as suggested by @BrenBarn in the comments